# cmake mingw-w64: strange error when trying to build

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw-w64, ninja

I have installed MinGW-w64 and built a simple Hello World Program. But the second time I run `cmake --build .` a strange error occurs.
When the Path variable is set to `C:/MinGW/bin` everything is fine and works. But when I set the Path to `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin` this happens:

```
PS C:\repos\hellovs\build> cmake ../ -G Ninja
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/repos/hellovs/build
PS C:\repos\hellovs\build> cmake --build ./
[2/2] Linking CXX executable HelloVS.exe
PS C:\repos\hellovs\build> cmake --build ./
ninja: error: FindFirstFileExA(c/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0): ╤шэЄръёшўхёър  ю°шсър т шьхэш Їрщыр, шьхэш яряъш шыш ьхЄъх Єюьр.
```

`HelloVS.exe` compiles normally the first time the build command is run.

Apparanteley Ninja tryies to use an invalid path. Any idea about how to fix this?

---

Seems like invalid dependencies have been generated:

```
PS C:\repos\hellovs\build> ninja -t recompact
PS C:\repos\hellovs\build> ninja -t deps
CMakeFiles/HelloVS.dir/main.cpp.obj: #deps 136, deps mtime 6109023486207704 (VALID)
    ../main.cpp
    C/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0/iostream
    C/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/c++config.h
    C/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/os_defines.h
    C/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bits/cpu_defines.h
    C/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0/pstl/pstl_config.h
    C/:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.1.0/ostream
...
```

Comment: Ninja manual seems to suggest that ninja relies on the compiler to generate dependencies. Can you check if `-MD` gcc flag functions correctly (outside of ninja)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how could I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, tried it myself and got the same broken dependencies. It means it's a GCC problem. I've skimmed though MSYS2 gcc patches, and they don't seem to change anything in this regard, so I suggest complaining on GCC bug tracker. In the meantime, you can either switch to Clang (which doesn't have this problem), or make a simple wrapper program that invokes GCC and fixes the files it generates, and tell CMake to use it instead of GCC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if you delete the generated `.ninja_deps`, the build will be successful for one time. Also, when I use Visual Studio "Open Folder" this problem does not seem to occur. But in Visual Studio COde and CLion it persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a GCC bug.

MSYS2 maintainers decided to not wait for the upstream and [patched it](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/9b7f67c5f620d1ba7ce951cfee3ce2328fb751f6).

Run `pacman -Syuu` from MSYS2 shell to update your packages.

Comment: Here is fix in gcc repo: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/1ba71fabb78b18884e9f479f45a257bab50e8959#diff-01d4a2754612370f4a498e10fb94692e0c7e4e9ea1e04fcf7d29c8037d81bb5b